# WCF Message body encryption with SSL

Tags: wcf, security, soap, encryption, wcf-security

I am new to WCF. I am investigating the right way to have message body encryption over HTTPS (mixing both transport and message level security at the moment)

I have HttpsGetEnabled.

Using WsHttpBinding, I still see the message body unencrypted

```
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="myCustomWsHttpBinding">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

I have also tried using custom binding but same result

```
<binding name="myCustomBinding">
  <security authenticationMode="CertificateOverTransport"
            messageProtectionOrder="EncryptBeforeSign"
            includeTimestamp="true"
            protectTokens="true"
            >
  </security>
  <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" />
  <httpsTransport/>
</binding>
```

How can we have message body encrypted when using Https? If I understand correctly message level security is independent of transport so using https is possible in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the custom binding, set authenticationMode to "mutualCertificate"

Comment: Thank you, I will try set-up mutual certificate

Comment: Just a quick question - Does TransportWithMessageCredential encrypt the message body? I have not changed the default protection level which I believe is Encrypt and Sign

Comment: it encrypts at the transport level only, so if you look at the message xml it will not seem encrypted like with regular ws-security. this is a valid option, all depending what you try to achive

Comment: Thank you, this is the behaviour I see in my custom dispatch message inspector. From MSDN, I read that by the time Dispatch message inspector is called, the message is already decrypted and so I thought the message body was encrypted. Which as you said is an incorrect understanding.

I want to be able to create a binding so that the message body is encrypted and client authenticates via a certificate. On service side I would like to log the message with encrypted body. But as you said using TransportWithMessageCredential will only encrypt at transport level and not message level.

Comment: if you need to log the enctyped body then first the body must be encrypted (not the case with transport with message cred) and second you could implement a custom message encoder

Comment: OK. I believe setting mode to Message gives encryption but its on Http whereas I am trying to get it work with Https hence the choice of transport with message which obviously leads to message body not encrypted.
I was looking at custom channel earlier today and do plan to explore custom message encoder.

If I were to implement custom message encoder to encrypt the body it will have to be from both client and service side. Am I right?

Comment: yes but don't need to implement an encoder that does encryption. let wcf do the encryption (if you use custom binding ssl and message encryption can be combined). you only build a wrapper encoder that logs the message and calls the internal encoder.

Comment: Thanks. I am not very clear about combining message security with Https using custom binding. Could you please let me know what authentication mode is used to require certificate at message level using custom binding? Using your tool I converted the wsHttpBinding for Message mode to a custom binding and it set the mode as SecureConversation. Would this be related to mutualCertificate that you mentioned earlier?

Comment: when ever secure conversation is the security mode, it means "use another security mode to get some session key, and then use this key to secure the messages in this session". the other security mode is specified in the authenticationMode property of the secureConversationBootstrap element